# How can I do subresource with Spring?

Tags: spring, rest

I'm working with Spring. How can I do sub-resource, just like JAX-RS?

```
@RestController("parents")
public class ParentsController {
}

@RestController("children")
public class ChildrenController {
}
```

Is there any plain way to do with Spring? So that I can do following?

Controlled by the `ParentsController`.

```
/parents
/parents/{id}
```

Controlled by the `ChildrenController`.

```
/parents/{id}/children
/parents/{id}/children/{id}
```

### EDIT

Yet another intention of this question is making the `ChildrenController` available on multiple request mappings so that I can also do

```
/children
/children/{id}
```